# After upgrading my Ubuntu 13.10 to 14.04, I constantly face internet connection disconnection

Tags: wireless, 14.04, internet

Problem : My internet connection get disconnected constantly for a while, but it get resolved by itself after a while.

Situation : This happens after I upgrade my **Ubuntu OS 13.10** to **14.04** and this problem only appear when I get connected to my office wifi. (I don't get this trouble at my home wifi)

Clue : When I do a ping, I found this message when the internet connection is down:

```
ping: sendmsg: No buffer space available
```

Could anybody help me to resolve this problem? This problem is really annoying for me.

Comment: What wifi card do you have?

Comment: 02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 06)
04:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR9462 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)

Comment: Could be [bug #1268833](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1268833)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is most likely something to do with your office's wifi setup. There is probably a configuration set up in a router that is causing the new update to stutter on a certain setting. There probably isn't a way to fix this, but just make sure that:

1. Your drivers are all updated. 
   This could cause some issues. Simply update your drivers and this could solve the issue.
2. Search specific issues on your WiFi adapter describing the issue your having.
3. If all else fails, do a fresh install of Ubuntu

Comment: Thx @Adam, I will try your last suggestion (do a fresh install).

Comment: I still get this problem eventhough I've done the fresh install :(

Comment: I think you are right @Adam, it was my office's wifi setup. I recognized this because when I moved to other place, I could use their wifi without any problem. -mark this as resolved then-